# fscanf is consistently returning 0 when it should be returning 1

Tags: c, matrix, file-io, scanf

I have a function that takes a file stream and reads the integers stored in that file into a 1D matrix. The problem I'm having is that my fscanf is consistently returning 0, not 1 like I expect it. I know for a fact that the beginning of my file is formatted correctly and as expected, but I can't figure out why it won't read the very first line. What am I doing wrong?

```c
/* FUNCTION: readToMatrix
    DESCRIPTION:
        This takes an input stream and reads the file (as described in the header documentation),
        filling the array with the integers contained in the input file stream.
    INPUTS:
        file stream, int *array, matrix width
    OUTPUTS:
        Writes to array
    RETURN:
        Returns 0 on success, nonzero on an unexpected failure.
*/

int readToMatrix( FILE *input, int *array, size_t matWidth )
{
    int x,y;
    long num;

    for ( y = 0; y < matWidth; ++y)
    {
        for ( x = 0; x < matWidth-1; ++x )
        {
            // if fscanf doesn't read 1 number or if EOF then return
            if ( fscanf(input, "%ld,", &num) != 1 || feof(input) ) return -1;
            array[x + y*matWidth] = num;
        }
        if ( fscanf(input, "%ld ", &num) != 1 || feof(input) ) return -1;
        array[x + y*matWidth] = num;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: Here is a short snippet of the beginning of the input file.

```
12177,12690,12499,12985,13005,12574,12882,12896,13026,14539,13704,13539,15182,14361,14539,15333,14615,15231,
```

Comment: Where did you open your file ?

Comment: The file was opened in the function that called it.

Comment: Which fscanf call?

Comment: `fscanf is consistently returning 0, not 1 like I expect` Always remember, when the question is "Is there a bug in the standard library, or am I doing something wrong?" The answer is almost always "you're doing something wrong".

Comment: @immibis the first one is giving problems on the first time it's executed.

Comment: the `|| feof(input)` isn't doing anything... if you had reached end of file, `fscanf()` would fail and `feof()` wouldn't get called, and if not then `feof()` should never return non-zero (unless you had an uncleared EOF from earlier).

Comment: @John3136 of course I'm doing something wrong! Just need to figure out what it is.

Comment: It might help to see the contents of your input file...

Comment: @Dimitri good point, I will flip the two statements instead.

Comment: @Dmitri I have added a small portion of the beginning of the input file.

Comment: You're just returning -1 if `fscanf()` fails, or on end-of-file which would cause `fscanf()` to fail anyway.  You don't need the `feof()` calls at all, in any order.  Besides, `feof()` wouldn't return true until *after* `fscanf()` failed from EOF.

Comment: Why not `if (fscanf(input, "%ld,", &num) != 1) return 1;` (try not to return a negative value to the shell)

Comment: Not awake yet `:)`

Comment: Don't use commas to separate numbers... use spaces

Comment: @"Luis Colorado" I have no choice, I did not write the matrix file, and the person who gave this to me wants it done this way.

Answer (score 1):

there are some small problems in your loop. 
fix these ,then it can run correctly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int readToMatrix( FILE *input, int *array, size_t matWidth , size_t matHeight)
{
    int x,y;
    long num;
    for ( y = 0; y < matHeight; y++)
    {
        for ( x = 0; x < matWidth; x++ )
        {
            // if fscanf doesn't read 1 number or if EOF then return
            if ( fscanf(input, "%ld,", &num) != 1 || feof(input) ) return -1;    
            array[x + y*matWidth] = num;
        }    
    }       
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    FILE *fd;
    int matWidth = 5 ;
    int matHeight = 5;
    int array[18]; 
    int i;
    fd=fopen("matrix.txt","r");
    if(fd == NULL)
    {
        printf("open failed!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        readToMatrix( fd, array, matWidth , matHeight);
        fclose(fd);
    }
    for(i=0;i<18;i++)
    {
        printf("%d:%d\n",i,array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is matrix.txt:

```
12177,12690,12499,12985,13005,12574,12882,12896,13026,14539,13704,13539,15182,14361,14539,15333,14615,15231
```

output:
0:12177
1:12690
2:12499
3:12985
4:13005
5:12574
6:12882
7:12896
8:13026
9:14539
10:13704
11:13539
12:15182
13:14361
14:14539
15:15333
16:14615
17:15231

Comment: No, my loops were correct. The matrix is constrained as a square, so it's x and y dimensions will be the same.

Comment: @UnclePutin please try my code of this version, it can read "," as separator .

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. For some reason, passing the file stream into the function was not working. When I made the function create the file stream and open the file in the function itself (as it probably should be), everything worked perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?  Can you illustrate your own answer to your own question, and this will not be a "work for nothing" thing?